# Samsung Champ (GT-3303k) to be converted to Andoid?

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung Champ. Model number GT or CT3303k. I want to convert this phone to an android system. Can this be possible for my phone specifically ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope sadly you cannoy convert it to Android.

Comment: Reason: very low end device from 2010. Not possible.